# StreamWriter() isn't working as it should?

Tags: c#

Ive got an array of properties from an object that I want append to a textfile.

Here is my code:

```
StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter("Cars.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     Writer.Write(CarProps[i]); 
  }
```

I added stuff to the textfile manually, but when I run the program, the text file comes up blank.

Comment: Try adding the append to `true` and use `using`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `using` statement to flush the writer:

```
using(var writer = new StreamWriter("Cars.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        writer.Write(CarProps[i]); 
    }
}
```

If you don't set [`StreamWriter.AutoFlush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`, it won't write to the stream immediately. Therefore you have to call [`Flush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or `Close` manually. `Flush` is called  on `Dispose` which is invoked by the `using`.

Comment: Would you mind checking my answer if it is A right way to do it? Thanks :)